# How to use my PHP regular expression in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, node.js, preg-match-all

I have a regular expression in PHP but when I ported it to Node.js, the output I'm getting is not the same as the one I get from PHP, but I think it is because I don't really know how to make PREG_SET_ORDER work in Node.js.

---

**Example text:**

```
INPUT - Each line represents a line inside a text file. 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"!?Text" (1234)                                         1234-4321
"#1 Text" (1234)                                        1234-????
#2 Text (1234) {Some text (#1.1)}                       1234
Text (1234)                                             1234
Some Other Text: More Text here 1234-4321 (1234) (V)    1234
```

**PHP:**

```
preg_match_all("/^((.*?) *\((\d+)\))(?: *\{((.*?) *\((.+?)\)) *\})?/m",$data,$r, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$i = 0;
foreach($r as $a) {
    array_splice($a, 0, 2);
    if(count($a) > 2) {
        array_splice($a, 2, 1);
    }
    print_r($a);
}
```

**Node.js:**

```
var regex = /^((.*?) *\((\d+)\))(?: *\{((.*?) *\((.+?)\)) *\})?/mg
var result = data.toString().match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

**PHP (Output):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => "!?Text"
    [1] => 1234
)
Array
(
    [0] => "#1 Text"
    [1] => 1234
)
Array
(
    [0] => #2 Text
    [1] => 1234
    [2] => Some text
    [3] => #1.1
)
Array
(
    [0] => Text
    [1] => 1234
)
Array
(
    [0] => Some Other Text: More Text here 1234-4321
    [1] => 1234
)
```

**Node.js (Output):**

```
[ '"!?Text" (1234)',
  '"#1 Text" (1234)',
  '#2 Text (1234) {Some text (#1.1)}',
  'Text (1234)',
  'Some Other Text: More Text here 1234-4321 (1234)' ]
```

Comment: The match-all seems to be hard. Why not split by line and try to match each line individually?

Comment: are you sure data is being populated correctly, or that the toString() function is working properly

Comment: It seems I am getting some matches from the function but how do I make PREG_SET_ORDER work in node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I managed to get it to work like this:

```
function data_to_array(data) {
   var regex = '^((.*?) *\\((\\d+)\\))(?: *\\{((.*?) *\\((.+?)\\)) *\\})?';
   var Regex = new RegExp(regex, 'mg');
   var Matches = data.match(Regex);
   matchesArray = new Array();
   for (var i in Matches) {
      ngRegex = new RegExp(regex);
      ngMatches = Matches[i].match(ngRegex);
      ngMatches.splice(0, 2);
      if(ngMatches.length > 2) {
        ngMatches.splice(2, 1);
      }
      matchesArray.push(ngMatches);
   }
   return matchesArray;
}

var output = data_to_array(data.toString());
console.log(output);
```